# Retrieving full URL from cgi.FieldStorage

Tags: python, cgi

I'm passing a URL to a python script using `cgi.FieldStorage()`:

```
http://localhost/cgi-bin/test.py?file=http://localhost/test.xml
```

`test.py` just contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
print "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
print "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=x-user-defined"
print "Accept-Ranges: bytes"
print
print cgi.FieldStorage()
```

and the result is

```
FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('file', 'http:/localhost/test.xml')])
```

Note that the URL only contains `http:/localhost` - how do I pass the full encoded URI so that file is the whole URI? I've tried encoding the file parameter (`http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2ftext.xml`) but this also doesn't work

The screenshot shows that the output to the webpage isn't what is expected, but that the encoded url is correct

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CGI script works fine for me using Apache 2.4.10 and Firefox (curl also). What web server and browser are you using?

My guess is that you are using Python's [`CGIHTTPServer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/cgihttpserver.html#module-CGIHTTPServer), or something based on it. This exhibits the problem that you identify. `CGIHTTPServer` assumes that it is being provided with a path to a CGI script so it collapses the path without regard to any query string that might be present. Collapsing the path removes duplicate forward slashes as well as relative path elements such as `..`.

If you are using this web server I don't see any obvious way around by changing the URL. You won't be using it in production, so perhaps look at another web server such as Apache, nginx, lighttpd etc.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Yes - I am using CGIHTTPServer, I've spent the day googling the issue and hadn't come across any other description of the problem, so I'm glad I'm not going totally mad!

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your query parameters, you should be encoding them:

```
>>> from urllib import urlencode
>>> urlencode({'file': 'http://localhost/test.xml', 'other': 'this/has/forward/slashes'})
'other=this%2Fhas%2Fforward%2Fslashes&file=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest.xml'
```

Comment: Spinning up a quick cgi server and including your script, if I visit ```http://localhost:9999/cgi-bin/test.py?other=this%2Fhas%2Fforward%2Fslashes&file=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Ftest.xml``` I get back ```FieldStorage(None, None, [MiniFieldStorage('other', 'this/has/forward/slashes'), MiniFieldStorage('file', 'http://localhost/test.xml')])```

Comment: That's really weird - nothing I'm trying is working :/

Comment: I've added a screenshot to prove that it's really not working(!)